# Normal font appears italic on some devices. Why and how to fix?

Tags: android

The problem is that text in `TextView` looks fine on Android emulator, but it doesn't on the actual device. This is not my device and I'm not familiar with Android system, so I don't know if it's somehow overridden by system settings.

Here is how it looks on the emulator:

[image: Emulator screenshot]

And here is how it looks on the device:

[image: Actual device]

TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/AppTheme.Text.StepperHeader"
    android:text="Header"/>
```

Style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- No text-related settings here. -->
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Text">
    <item name="android:textColor">#1F1F1F</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Text.StepperHeader">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>
```

If the problem is in `AppCompat` theme as a parent — which one should I use instead?
I want a consistent app look on all devices. Can you explain why it's happening and how to fix it?

Comment: I don't see cursive anywhere.  Do you mean itallic?

Comment: Is it possible this is related to language or region settings on the device?

Comment: @GabeSechan yes, I meant italic. Fixed the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To be able to get same font result on (almost) every device, use a custom font. You can download one from websites like [DaFont](http://www.dafont.com/), etc. Then, you can apply your custom font easily (and without a need to get into the details of Android styles)   to your UI widgets using [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) library. See its piece-of-cake documentation for examples usage.

Comment: Thank you for the library, but I'm looking for some built-in solution because using this library to install the default Roboto font looks like extra and unnecessary complexity.